# Permission denied for Nginx even if www-data user has group write access

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, nginx

Nginx is not able to write to log file even if its user has write group access.
Here are some details:

**www-data user is in ubuntu group:**

```
$ id www-data
uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data),1000(ubuntu)
```

**/opt/logs/ is group writable:**

```
$ ls -ld /opt/logs/
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 2012-07-27 02:47 /opt/logs/
```

**www-data user can create /opt/logs/1 as expected:**

```
$ su www-data
$ touch /opt/logs/1
$ ls -l /opt/logs/1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data 0 2012-07-27 02:47 /opt/logs/1
```

**Nginx user:groups:**

```
var_dump(system('whoami'), system('groups'));
// string 'www-data' (length=8)
// string 'www-data ubuntu' (length=15)
```

**But Nginx is not able to write:**

```
Warning: file_put_contents(/opt/logs/Error.log) function.file-put-contents failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

**/opt/logs/Error.log doesn't exist**

So why coudn't it write to file?

Comment: any /opt/logs/Error.log exists ?, if yes, what's the permission ?. check if parent directory permission also. any apparmor or selinux ?

Comment: No, /opt/logs/Error.log doesn't exist. If it's apparmor or selinux, why can I create a file over shell?

Comment: Furthermore, I chowned it to ubuntu:www-data and back to ubuntu:ubuntu and now it can write!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible reason: when you add `www-data` user to the `ubuntu` group, it only affects sessions started later.

`su - www-data -s /bin/bash` creates a new session, so it works fine. But Nginx is still running as `www-data` user, therefore I suspect that it's the reason for the above error.

*(if you switch to the `www-data` user before doing a `usermod -a -G ubuntu www-data`, I'm pretty sure that you will only see `uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data)` when typing `id`)*

Either restarting Nginx or do a `newgrp ubuntu` after switching to `www-data` user to make it take effect immediately.